# \linespread in LaTeX article class

Tags: line-spacing

I am employing LaTeX to draft a scientific manuscript for publication.

The journal specifications are that main text be double-spaced (`\linespread{2}`) and that references and figure/table captions be single-spaced (`\linespread{1}`).

However, when I do this, references are not single-spaced.

I am using the ACM bibliography style.

Any thoughts?

Comment: 1) `double-spaced` is not equivalent to `\linespread{2}` –  see the commented code of `setspace` . (2) It's better to load `setspace` and use  `\doublespacing` and `singlespacing` directives (or the `singlespace` environment).

Comment: @Bernard Thanks! Worked like a charm.